# Como validar la cantidad de caracteres en un texto con Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Tengo que validar que una variable contenga entre 8 y 15 caracteres, tengo el siguiente código

```
Match matchLongitud = Regex.Match(pass, @"^\w{8,15}\b");
if (!matchLongitud.Success)
    return false;
```

Pense que el problema estaba en esta linea `if (!matchLongitud.Success)` le quite el `!` pero aun asi no funciona.

El problema radica en en que he probado con distintas longitudes, pero igual el `Success` dice `false`, no se si la condición del `Reguex` esta bien definida

espero puedan ayudarme con esto, gracias de antemano

Comment: Exite la funcion minlength y maxlength para casos asi, que lenguaje usas ?

Comment: hola, uso C#, ilustrame amigo jajaja :D

Comment: pass.length contiene la cantidad de caracteres que hay en la cadena, usar una regexp para eso es matar mosquitos con cañones...

Comment: Te sirve un metodo sin regex? la variable la obtienes de algun textbox?

Comment: @gbianchi ya hice asi la validación, y funciono, gracias por la ayuda, igual me gustaría saber como funcionaria con el Regex.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia tu expresión regular por:

```
//Busca exactitud en la coincidencia encontrada que comience y termine, sino
//Tendrias que poner el caracter ? detras de tu \b en el anterior patrón que usabas
Match matchLongitud = Regex.Match(pass, @"^\w{8,15}$");
```

Comment: Hola, no funciona si la cadena tiene un carácter como - o /

Comment: entonces no seria \w tendria que ser `^[\w-\/]{8,15}$`

Comment: Estaba por votar +1, pero leí el comentario sobre poner `\b?` y ahí o no lo entiendo o me parece que haría todo lo contrario a lo que está preguntando